# Angular/Ionic How do i add components to html page based on db data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Lets say that im pulling some data from firebase db with:

```
this.invData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}/inventory`).valueChanges());
    this.invData.subscribe(invdata =>{
    this.invData=invdata      
    console.log(this.invData);
    console.log(this.invData.apple)//this returns 3 
});
```

i can display this number of apples on html page with {{invData.apple}} but for example if i want to put some clickable interactable components i mean radiobuttons or select components  how do i do that ?

Like if invData.apple is greater than 1  display a radiobutton if not do not display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for ngIf: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

An example of what you're asking for is below (showing a button, not a radio in this case). The angular documentation will give other examples (e.g. else blocks)

```
<p *ngIf="invData?.apple > 1">
      <button ion-button full (click)="closeModal()">
        Close
      </button>
</p>
```